# How do you approximate state transitions based on a person's attributes?

Tags: probability, distribution, genetic-algorithm, anylogic, propensity-score-matching

Suppose you have a customer attribute classified as high, medium and low. Different class of customers are supposed to have different probabilities of state transition. Are you creating micro ML models  to get different probabilities or you are just using relative percentages of past transitions based on historical data?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about an implementation choice.  That's a decision to be made by the modeler, and a matter of opinion regarding which choice best reflects how the system you want to model actually behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using distributions based on historical data is the thing most typically used if you have transition data... nevertheless depending on the situation you can also use prediction models to know what transition the agent will use, as long as you have independent variables that you can use to predict this...

This prediction can be done with ML models or statistical models, depending on the situation

You can also go further and use artificial intelligence if there is a constant sequential decision making on where to transition, you can do this if you want to optimize the behavior of these customers... reinforcement learning is used for that and you can use your simulation model to generate a policy for the decision making process of these customers.

Comment: if we combine like 3-4 attributes and create bayesian priori probabilities or joint probabilities with branches between transition where ML models show weak correlation, does it make sense?